What "Texas and federal law"s is SpaceX "in violation of"?
According to this Space News article, FAA Administrator Mike Whitaker said that SpaceX was "in violation of Texas and federal law" and that is why the license for Starship was delayed. SpaceX later said that "every statement he [(Whitaker)] made was incorrect"
What I can't seem to find is what laws they actually are in violation of. So, does anyone know or has it been released somewhere what laws they are in violation of?

Depending on the level of detail you want, Law SE might be a better venue. Assuming you don't want chapter-and-verse on precisely which laws were violated

The Ars Technia article "The war of words between SpaceX and the FAA keeps escalating"

the SpaceX statement (released on X )

and Ars Technica's Elon Musk threatens to sue FAA after feds propose fining SpaceX $633,000


lay the story out.  Drawing mostly from The war of words...:

SpaceX says fines levied against it this year by the Texas Commission on Environmental Quality (TCEQ) and the Environmental Protection Agency (EPA) related to the launch pad's water system were "entirely tied to disagreements over paperwork" and not any dumping of pollutants into the environment around the Starship launch site.
...
Whitaker said the FAA levied fines on SpaceX for Falcon 9 launches last year because SpaceX launched the missions without a permit. SpaceX contends it was fully licensed, and the FAA has "incorrectly alleged non-compliances."
One of the fines has to do with SpaceX's relocation of a fuel farm at its launch pad at NASA's Kennedy Space Center in Florida. Whitaker alleged SpaceX moved it "closer to the population and did not do a risk analysis before launching." SpaceX says it moved the fuel farm farther from publicly accessible areas, and range safety authorities in Florida approved the change.

From Elon Musk threatens to sue FAA...

What did they do?
According to the FAA, SpaceX violated its launch license requirements twice during a Falcon 9 launch of an Indonesian communications satellite on June 18, 2023. SpaceX's launch team used a new control room at the company's Hangar X facility at Kennedy Space Center instead of the FAA-approved control rooms SpaceX previously used at the Florida spaceport. In addition, SpaceX's launch team did not conduct a readiness poll two hours before liftoff.
More than a month before this launch, SpaceX requested FAA approval to use the new launch control room and remove the readiness poll from its countdown procedures. The FAA says it informed SpaceX it would not approve the changes in time for the June 18 launch last year, but SpaceX went ahead with the mission.
The new control center at Hangar X debuted last year, and NASA approved its use for the launch of an astronaut crew to the International Space Station in August 2023.
On a separate launch of a Falcon Heavy rocket a month later, the FAA alleges SpaceX used an "unapproved rocket propellant farm" located at Launch Complex 39A at Kennedy. Nine days before the Falcon Heavy mission, SpaceX asked the FAA for an update to its launch license nine days prior to reflect the change to the ground fuel facility at the launch pad. Similar to the situation a month before, the FAA says it told SpaceX it would not grant the company's request in time for the launch.
The FAA said SpaceX has 30 days to respond to the allegations.
The last time the FAA imposed a fine on a commercial space company was last year when regulators fined SpaceX $175,000 for not submitting launch collision avoidance analysis trajectory data to the FAA for a Falcon 9 launch in 2022. SpaceX paid the fine in October 2023.

My maybe-partly-informed opinion:
SpaceX probably was in violation of the letter, but not the spirit, of the law for the FAA stuff. They wanted to move faster than the paperwork would clear and ended up doing things before the FAA signed off on them, even though the FAA ultimately signed off. Like it or not, the FAA de jure owns the skies above the US, and if you're using their skies, their inability to do paperwork on your schedule is your problem, not theirs.  (Full disclosure: I have had history of arguing with the FAA. I ultimately won my argument, but it took a year).
The TCEQ issue is much less clear to me.  Apparently per NBC and other news outlets TCEQ has issued a notice of a violation on the water deluge system.  SpaceX has contested this, in their statement they say

a. SpaceX was operating under a permit from the TCEQ. TCEQ staff were physically present during operation of the deluge. FAA and FWS [Fish and Wildlife Service] have evaluated use of the deluge and determined no environmental risk.
b. At EPA's request, SpaceX is seeking a different type of permit to cover these operations. The FAA, TCEQ, and EPA have confirmed that deluge operations may continue in the interim, and operation of the system will not change under this new permit.

So SpaceX might also be not-quite-permitted but operating under the expectation of updated permits, or something like that. Or it's possible that SpaceX is actually right about not violating any Texas environmental regulations.

Thank you so much for this. Just curious (if you're okay with shairng) how did you wind up in a year long arguement with the FAA?

@Starship long story short, when I came out as trans they demanded a neurological workup, which they were doing to everybody. I became one of several people campaigning for equal treatment. Related Aviation SE post here though not with a ton of detail, not that I remember the whole shebang very well anymore. I mostly wrote a bunch of pissed off letters and tried to involve my (entirely useless) Congressman and (slightly less useless) NCTE.

@Starship if you'd like to know more I don't mind sharing (if I can dig up what happened / remember more), but we should probably use a chat room for it.

"their inability to do paperwork on your schedule is your problem, not theirs" – If you know that the FAA moves slow, but you still apply for a permit for a new propellant farm a mere nine days before you start using it, then it arguably is your problem. I mean, it's not like the propellant farm suddenly appeared out of nowhere – SpaceX had been building it for months. Whatever you may think about the bureaucratic processes of the FAA, there is no way on Earth that a proper environmental and safety analysis of something as complex as an industrial propellant farm can be done in a week.

I have a family member who works for TCEQ (not in the region(s) of Texas where SpaceX operates). Any facility in Texas that emits air pollution or liquid waste must have a permit to do so (and by "facility" it can be as small as a natural gas well generator fueled by the raw gas so there are tens of thousands of these permits). The permit spells out what pollutants they are allowed to emit and how much. The facility has to pay a 3rd party to test their facility to see if they are in compliance. It does not sound like something Musk would really groove on.

@JörgWMittag I wasn't aware of the timetable, but even before knowing that I agreed with you. Maybe I need to change the tone of the part you quoted some. Thanks for pointing at it

@JörgWMittag - I would be interested in a question that asks if there is any evidence that SpaceX has actually ever been delayed by the FAA. The only evidence that I know of are claims by Elon more than once (I think this is the second time?) that they are ready to fly but are held up by the FAA, when there was evidence that they were not quite ready. This particular situation seems more plausible that they could launch before December though, but the catch attempt throws a wrench in that prediction, are they really ready as of today to catch a booster? Even recently they were seen testing it.

@StevePemberton: I can only remember one time. SpaceX launched SN8 without a launch license. As a result, the FAA required an FAA overseer present in the launch control center for (at least) the launch of SN9. On one of the days that SpaceX planned a launch attempt of SN9, that FAA overseer got stuck in traffic, and thus, the launch had to be scrubbed. This may or may not have caused a couple of days of delay. Other than that, I am not aware of any examples. I would argue that if SpaceX completes a successful Wet Dress Rehearsal in the coming weeks, then it will, indeed, be truly held up.

@JörgWMittag - I agree as far as the launch itself, I just think an unknown is whether they have completed all tests and modifications for the catch. If from this point forward we see only maybe one or two more tests moving the arms, it could be theorized that they are ready to catch but are just filling the time with additional rehearsals. But if any more modifications are seen that probably would indicate it is still being finalized. Barely mentioned it seems in most news reports about the FAA situation is the enormity of what SpaceX will be attempting on this flight.
